# Realm not generating RealmProxy classes in Java/Kotlin project when using kapt

Tags: java, android, kotlin, apt, kapt

I'm trying to integrate realm in a Java/Kotlin project, but kapt is not generating RealmProxy classes even for .java files

I've updated realm because of [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2491), but still not working

Gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

project.ext {
    daggerVersion = '2.2'
}

dependencies {

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3"

    annotationProcessor group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: "${daggerVersion}"
    compile group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: "${daggerVersion}"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
    provided group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.annotation', version: '10.0-b28'
    testAnnotationProcessor group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: "${daggerVersion}"
    testCompile group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: "${daggerVersion}"
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: "${daggerVersion}"
    androidTestCompile group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: "${daggerVersion}"
}
...
```

Project File:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'

    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
    }
}
...
```

Java Model file:

```
@RealmClass
public class NotificationEventsModel extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long classPK;

    @SerializedName("userNotificationEventsCount")
    private int eventsCount;

}
```

Kotlin Model file:

```
@RealmClass open class PageModel(

    open var classPK: Long = 0,
    open var content: String? = null,
    @PrimaryKey
    open var id: Long = 0,

) : RealmObject() {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by declaring the realm-android plugin as the last one in the list of plugins and also by switching from annotationProcessor to Kapt, like below:

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3'
compile group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: "${daggerVersion}"
kapt group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: "${daggerVersion}"
kaptTest group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: "${daggerVersion}"
kaptAndroidTest group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: "${daggerVersion}"
```

Comment: Just as a remark, with AS 3.x you don't have to use `retrolambda` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should either extend `RealmObject`:

```
open class PageModel(...) : RealmObject()
```

Or [use the `@RealmClass` annotation and implement `RealmModel`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface):

```
@RealmClass 
open class PageModel(...) : RealmModel
```

Perhaps the annotation used together with the subclassing is what trips up Realm.

Comment: I already did this, but as said in https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/ javac does not propagate Inherited annotations down the class hierarchies. So I also used RealmClass annotation

Answer (score 0):

`kotlin-kapt` plugin instructs gradle to use kapt3. Maybe is this related, and Realm plugin has some issue with it? Shouldn't be the case, as from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936257/kapt3-java-io-file-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-string#43067311) seems to be working, but is also for an older version of the plugin (which makes it even more weird).

Answer (score 0):

//build gradle (app)

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
>
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' 
>   apply plugin : 'realm-android' 
>   apply plugin :'kotlin-android-extensions'
>
> realm {
>       kotlinExtensionsEnabled = true 
>   }

//build gradle (project)
 classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.9.0"